# there is an error that I can't handle in the react table next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-table

when i do a search on the last page of the table there is an error which i don't know how to handle. but when I search on the first page the error doesn't appear, the error appears only on the last page when doing a search. with an error

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

. even though I have defined the 'id' as a keyfield

this is the code i use.

```
const options = {
custom: true,
sizePerPage: 5,
paginationSize: 4,
pageStartIndex: 1,
firstPageText: "First",
prePageText: "Back",
nextPageText: "Next",
lastPageText: "Last",
nextPageTitle: "First page",
prePageTitle: "Pre page",
firstPageTitle: "Next page",
lastPageTitle: "Last page",
showTotal: true,
totalSize: datas.length};



const contentTable = ({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => (
    <div>
      <PaginationListStandalone {...paginationProps} />
      <ToolkitProvider keyField="id" columns={columns} data={datas} search>
        {(toolkitprops) => (
          <div>
            <SearchBar {...toolkitprops.searchProps} />
            <BootstrapTable
              striped
              hover
              {...toolkitprops.baseProps}
              {...paginationTableProps}
            />
          </div>
        )}
      </ToolkitProvider>
      <PaginationListStandalone {...paginationProps} />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>
        PaginationProvider will care the data size change. You dont do anything
      </h2>
      <PaginationProvider pagination={paginationFactory(options)}>
        {contentTable}
      </PaginationProvider>
    </div>
  );
```

full code: [ReactJs-Table-Next](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-table-next-gx193?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. I have no idea what pages you are writing about, let alone what error: Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: That's a weird error and I don't think it's on your end. It's probably a bug in `react-bootstrap-table2` and you should [open a new issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues) on their Github page.

Comment: I've found a solution, by downgrading the version of react-bootstrap-table-next from version 4.0.3 to 4.0.2 or below

Comment: this could be such a great project if the owner didnt abandon it completely these past 3 years